# Spawn Download with Client Side Script

Tags: javascript, download, client

In an application that runs client-side, in browser, written in Javascript, you can use local storage to persist state. If the user requires the ability to extract their data from the client-side application, one option is posting the content to the server and having the server echo it back with the correct content-type and other headers to spawn a download operation.

Is there any way to spawn such a download operation using purely client-side script, without posting the content to a server and echoing it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered how to do this: you can use `Blob`, `createObjectURL()` and `anchor` tags.

This JSFiddle shows a solution that works in Chrome and Internet Explorer and even supports drag-and-drop saving in Chrome (you can drag the Save-button into Windows Explorer to save the document.) http://jsfiddle.net/fa9y6/9/

First, you must construct a `Blob` to save:

```
var blob = new Blob([ $('#documentContent').val() ], { type: mimeType });
```

Saving it as a file is easiest in Internet Explorer:

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename); 
}
```

In Chrome (*and Firefox*), you can construct an `anchor` tag and `click()` it:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = filename;
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.click();
if (a.remove) a.remove();
```

To support drag-and-drop file saving, you need to attach a handler to `dragstart`:

```
if (window.chrome) {
     document.body.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
         // Some use a class, here. My sample only has one save button.
         if (e.target.id == 'downloadButton') {      
             var blob = new Blob([ $('#documentContent').val() ], { type: mimeType });
             e.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', [mimeType, $('#fileName').val(), window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)].join(':'));
         }
     });
}
```

(*I have not performed thorough browser-compatibility testing in older browser versions.*)

Comment: It does i tested myself in a project

Answer (score 3):

Check out [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) which provides a `saveAs` function:

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

It's compatible with IE10+.